# IFC.js from WIT access WIV

Tags: javascript, ifc

This is a very general question.
I know there're two types of structures that we can code with ifc.js.

- WIT (Three.js
- WIV (WebIFCViewer

WIV has lots of convenient tools, that we can just use right away, but I would like to ask if it's possible that we access the WIV functions from WIT?

I would like to make my own controls from three.js(WIT) while also have the convenient functions from WIV.
Is this possible? If so, how can I access the WIV viewer from WIT.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

WIV is a wrapper around WIT. So you cannot access all WIT functionality from WIV. You can however, access WIT from WIV though. Try installing WIV and WIT and that way you could create your own controls.

You can check the below link for more info

https://ifcjs.github.io/info/docs/Guide/web-ifc-viewer/Introduction

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, there's no easy way to call WIV functions to WIT, like it is the other way around, the reason is WIT is built on top of WIV,